# Why is max and min of numpy array nan?

Tags: python, numpy, max, nan

What could be the reason, why the max and min of my numpy array is nan?
I checked my array with:

```
for i in range(data[0]):
    if data[i] == numpy.nan:
        print("nan")
```

And there is no nan in my data.
Is my search wrong?
If not: What could be the reason for max and min being nan?

Comment: Your snippet does not include `max` or `min`. Please include minimal code and required values so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: The way to check for nan is `if numpy.isnan(data[i])`

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, 4])

print(f'a.max() = {a.max()}')
print(f'np.nanmax(a) = {np.nanmax(a)}')

print(f'a.min() = {a.min()}')
print(f'np.nanmin(a) = {np.nanmin(a)}')
```

Output:

```
a.max() = nan
np.nanmax(a) = 4.0
a.min() = nan
np.nanmin(a) = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

*Balaji Ambresh* showed precisely how to find *min* / *max* even
if the source array contains *NaN*, there is nothing to add on this matter.

But your code sample contains also other flaws that deserve to be pointed out.

1. Your loop contains `for i in range(data[0]):`.
   You probably wanted to execute this loop for **each** element of *data*,
   but your loop will be executed as many times as the value of
   the initial element of *data*.

   Variations:

   - If it is e.g. *1*, it will be executed only once.
   - If it is *0* or negative, it will not be executed at all.
   - If it is >= than the size of *data*, *IndexError* exception
     will be raised.
   - If your array contains at least 1 *NaN*, then the whole array
     is of *float* type (*NaN* is a special case of *float*) and you get
     *TypeError* exception: *'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted
     as an integer*.

   Remedium (one of possible variants): This loop should start with
   `for elem in data:` and the code inside should use *elem* as the
   current element of *data*.
2. The next line contains `if data[i] == numpy.nan:`.
   Even if you corrected it to `if elem == np.nan:`, the code inside
   the *if* block will **never** be executed.
   The reason is that *np.nan* is by definition **not** equal to any
   other value, even it this other value is another *np.nan*.

   Remedium: Change to *if np.isnan(elem):* (*Balaji* wrote in his comment
   **how** to change your code, I added **why**).

And finally: How to check **quickly** an array for *NaN*s:

1. To get a detailed list, whether each element is *NaN*, run `np.isnan(data)`
   and you will get a *bool* array.
2. To get a **single** answer, whether *data* contains at least one *NaN*,
   no matter where, run `np.isnan(data).any()`.

This code is shorter and runs significantly faster.

Comment: Sorry that's my fault. I wanted to write "for i range(data.shape[0])"

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `np.nan == x` is *always False*, even when x is `np.nan` . This is aligned with the NaN definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Check yourself:

```py
In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[5]: False
```

If you want to check if a number `x` is `np.nan`, you must use

```py
np.isnan(x)
```

If you want to get max/min of an np.array with nan's, use [`np.nanmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmax.html)/ [`np.nanmin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html):

```py
minval = np.nanmin(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy use np.nanmax(variable_name) and np.nanmin(variable_name)

```
import numpy as np
z=np.arange(10,20)
z=np.where(z<15,np.nan,z)#Making below 15 z value as nan.
print(z)
print("z max value excluding nan :",np.nanmax(z))
print("z min value excluding nan :",np.nanmin(z))
```